# Creating a SOAP client in C++ (VS 2010) without any third party library like gSOAP

Tags: c++, soap, soap-client

We need to make SOAP requests in C++. Basically a SOAP client. The catch is that ***we DON'T want to use any third party library like gSOAP. Reason being that the transactions are finance related***. We need to write the complete code ourselves. 
Please suggest ideas towards it. I believe that this is going to be very complex.

Any ideas towards this would be of great help. **Our environment is C++ on windows (VS 2010)** Please note that for now, we can assume that there is a single SOAP based web service (written in C#) for which we need to do it. Therefore, any complexity related to generalizing this SOAP client can be left out for now.

Comment: any SOAP element would be third-party for you, tbh, Microsoft's RPC/CLR based SOAP client is no btter (and is proprietary code). Unless you would  go and do gigantic work on reverse-engineering SOAP, your option is to use self-compiled OpenSource library.  HomeBrewed  creation would be likely _less_ secure. For .NET C# (note that there are various C# versions, e.g. a Mono one) there IS SOAP Client object provided by Microsoft

Comment: I suppose that first you'll need to write a driver to interact with the network interface.

Comment: Doing SOAP 'by hand' is not complicated in principle, but it gets tedious and error[-prone for large and/or very dynamic schemas. If I were you I'd probably build the client with gSoap first and then eliminate the dependency on it afterwards. gSoap-generated source code is a fairly straight-forward read, in my experience - especially if all your attributes are text-based.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately a SOAP request is a HTTP POST of XML data. You can build the XML yourself and use [IWinHttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383979(v=vs.85).aspx) to post that data to the server.